# v8: Access overrided method of an object outside a 'new' js context

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I try to change an embeded js engine from an very old nspr to v8 and hit some trouble with this feature.

Here what I want to do:

```
// C++
class myClass {
public:
    myClass();
    static void myClassConstructor(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args);
    static void myClass_method1(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args);
    static v8::Persistent<v8::Function> constructor;
}

 void JS_InitmyClass(Isolate *isolate, Local<Object> global) {
    v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> f = v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, MyClass::myClassConstructor);
    f->SetClassName(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,"myClass"));
    f->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
    f->PrototypeTemplate()->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "method1"), FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, myClass_method1->GetFunction()));
    global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate,"myClass"), f->GetFunction());
    if (myClass::constructor.IsEmpty())  
       myClass::constructor.Reset(isolate, f->GetFunction());
}

void myClass::myClassConstructor(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    EscapableHandleScope handle_scope(args.GetIsolate());
    myClass* ref = new myClass();
    args.This()->SetInternalField(0, External::New(args.GetIsolate(), ref));
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(handle_scope.Escape(args.This()));
}

void myClass::myClass_method1(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    // Here I want to create a new object (outside a 'new' js context) and return it
    EscapableHandleScope handle_scope(cx);
    myClass *ref = new myClass();
    Local<Function> f = Local<Function>::New(cx, myClass::constructor);
    Local<Object> newobj = f->NewInstance();
    newobj->SetInternalField(0, External::New(cx, ref));
    return handle_scope.Escape(newobj);
}

// Js
myClass.prototype.js_method = function () {

}
a = new myClass(); // a is [Object myClass] and got method1 & js_method available
a.js_method(); // ok
b = myClass.method1(); // b is [Object myClass] but only method1 is available
b.js_method(); // not ok
```

I understand that for a, the prototype has changed as I want, but for b, the old one is used so js_method can't be available. True ?
So how can I create an object in v8 without the js 'new', and have the same behaviour ?

I try a lot of things before ... if someone can help me, he will be very welcome :-)
Have a good day.